# Where to find Ribbon Command Component

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am trying to catch the click event on a built-in ribbon command. [This tutorial](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/02/27/how-an-office-add-in-intercepts-clicking-a-built-in-control/?thank=you&t=1411141120#comment-304228) is the only suggestion I found, but it depends on a component called Ribbon Command that has to be placed somehow on the AddIn.

There is no such component on the toolbox in Visual Studio!

Does the tutorial mean something else? If not, where do I find this component?

I am using Outlook 2010 and writing in C# under visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is repurpose a button - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633(v=office.12).aspx